# Conditionally copy information from an Excel table to another sheet

Tags: excel

I have a table in an Excel sheet that is made up of 4 columns. Columns 2-4 have formulas in them. The 4th column has temperatures in it, and once it hits a certain temperature range I would like columns 1-4 (preferably) to copy over into another sheet.

How can I do that? I have tried to do a vlookup, but I don’t think it works because of the formulas in columns 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example of data?

All i can think off is an lookup inside an 'If' statement

Eg.

```
| Column1 | Formula | Formula | Temperature  |
| Text    | text    | text    | 20           |
| Text    | text    | text    | 25           |
| Text    | text    | text    | 30           |
```

so maybe a helper column to the right

```
| Column1 | Formula | Formula | Temperature  |Helper column |
| Text    | text    | text    | 20           |      0       |
| Text    | text    | text    | 25           |      1       |
| Text    | text    | text    | 30           |      1       |
```

with the formula
    =if(Temperature>"value","1","0")
    =if(Temperature>"24","1","0")

Then use an if in your new column on different sheet saying

```
=if(Helper column = 1, column1, "")
```

In your new table

Hopefully that makes a bit of sense although it is tricky without seeing example data.
if you are ok with VBA this could probably be way easier to do!

Comment: Thanks Dean, I’m really bad at excel formulas so struggling!

Comment: Can I add a photo of my data on here?

Comment: Yes, Clicked edit and insert image it should prompt you with a page from imgur to upload a screenshot to :)

Comment: @EveAdams Instead of adding a photo, you should add your data as text, see [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).